# How show AlertDialog with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

i'am trying develop a game in android that, when my doll crash with a bottle in a screen, show a Dialog with 2 options but i don't know...

```
public void whenDollCrash(Grafico elementofaba,Grafico elementoBotella){

    if((elementofaba.getPosX()+elementofaba.getAncho()>=elementoBotella.getPosX()+15)&&
            (elementofaba.getPosX()+elementofaba.getAncho() <= elementoBotella.getPosX()+elementoBotella.getAncho()+15)&&
            (elementofaba.getPosY()+elementofaba.getAlto()>=elementoBotella.getPosY())
            && (elementofaba.getPosY()+elementofaba.getAlto() <= elementoBotella.getPosY()+elementoBotella.getAlto())){
        juego.detener();
        hiloFaba.detener();
        sonidoJuego.stop();
        golpe.start();

        Async a= main.new Async();
        a.execute();

        Log.i("parada", "esto furruca");

    }
```

and my class AsyncTask is the next.
    public class Async extends AsyncTask{
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;

```
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


            return null;

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
             builder =
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);


        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            builder.setMessage("¿Confirma la acción seleccionada?")
            .setTitle("Confirmacion")
            .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()  {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });
            builder.create().show();
        }
```

Help me!!

In the logCat always shows NullPointerException

Comment: where is the line where you get this error

Comment: In the LogCat shows in this line     builder =
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

Comment: are you using the asynctask inside MainActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guy looks really suspicious

```
Async a= main.new Async();
```

You should use something like this

```
  public class Async extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    WeakReference<Activity> activityWeakRef;

    public Async(Activity context) {
        activityWeakRef = new WeakReference<Activity>(context);
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


        return null;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (activityWeakRef != null && activityWeakRef.get() != null) {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activityWeakRef.get());
            builder.setMessage("¿Confirma la acción seleccionada?").setTitle("Confirmacion").setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.create().show();
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this in your custom view

```
Async a = new Async((Activity) getContext());
a.execute()
```

Comment: perfect, but the last 2 lines Aync a= new Async... doesn't work because in my code this lines are in a VistaJuego which extends from View

Comment: Every visible view has a context of Activity, so I see no particular reason why it would not work!?

Comment: my eclipse shows "no enclosing instance of type MainActivity is accesible" why???

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing, I see no MainActivity in my code. Make sure that the Async class is not inside MainActivity and is in a separate file.